# moiré pattern on 3D bump-mapped model

Tags: three.js, webgl

Anyone here knows how to resolve a moiré pattern issue as appeared [here](https://www.otakhi.com/public/mfdesigner/Scenes/Alien%20Spaceship)?

[image]

[image: close up]

The pattern came from a bump map applied repeatedly to a torus using three.js ([oTakhi platform](https://www.otakhi.com/pages/overview)).

I've set the minFilter to THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter, magFilter to THREE.NearestFilter, and anisotropy to 16 but it still appears.

Thanks

Comment: I am interested on this too, on my behalf I can tell I faced the same problem with bumpmaps while using normalmaps they render a little bit more nicer. Can you try with a normalmap?

Comment: I converted the bump map to a normal map using gimp and tested it out on a plane surface... same moire pattern appears.  This issue may not be related to three.js alone.  The browser's display sampling algorithm may be at fault as well.... still investigating.

Comment: Note also that I am using the FXAA post-processing filter, not the default anti-aliasing algorithm in three.js.